# HAWQ installation ERROR: Invalid username and/or password error!! on Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hawq, pivotaltracker, hortonworks-sandbox

Can somebody update on this, **I was installing HAWQ in HDP sandbox** in the standalone machine, but after completing half of that I stuck to the below step.

> Trying to add the HDB repository to the Ambari server and had the
>   issue with user name and password used.

**I was using the same username and password that sandbox provides.**

reference link for installation instruction article [failing point at 5] - http://hdb.docs.pivotal.io/201/hdb/install/install-ambari.html

[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are giving ambari admin username and password .Default is user "admin" and password is "admin"

Comment: Thanks for answering but after used admin/admin same issue persists. Can you drill out more this issue how to fix ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although the default username/password for Ambari is maria_dev/maria_dev, this also did not work out.

Comment: In my case the username/password was maria_dev/maria_dev, but having said that nothing works out, then I reset the Ambari password and it works.

Answer (score 0):

if you login through default password given by Hortonworks `[i.e. maria_dev/maria_dev]`, **go and reset the Ambari username & password.**

> how to reset the link is [[*]](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/14569/default-username-password-not-working-for-hortonwo.html)

After reset try again :

[image]

```
I hope this will help others.
```